# removing password from using qpdf is failing

Tags: ubuntu, qpdf

```
qpdf --password=pwd –-decrypt a.pdf b.pdf
```

This is failing with the following message

```
qpdf: unknown argument b.pdf
```

Password is correct and a.pdf exists.
All the examples on the net has the same format.

I am running the same on ubuntu 18.04. pdftk is no more available in ubuntu 18.

Answer (score 1):

changing the order of arguments worked. not sure why?

```
qpdf --decrypt --password=pwd a.pdf b.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing your same issue and I'm running qpdf version 8.4.0.
This is the syntax that worked for me:

```
qpdf inputfilename.pdf --password=mypassword --decrypt outputfilename.pdf
```

The first parameter after qpdf command is the input filename, the the options and as last parameter the output filename.

Answer (score 0):

I have just had a different permutation....
OSX 10.15.3, qpdf installed using brew, qpdf version 9.1.1

needed to use:
/usr/local/bin/qpdf a.pdf b.pdf --password=abc123 --decrypt

hth...